# Is it possible to show a web font's defined missing glyph U+0000 in a web browser? A.k.a. the ".notdef" or "not found" glyph

Tags: browser, fonts, webfonts

I'm working on some web font subsets and want to see what my font's `notdef / U+0000` character looks like on-screen, in a browser.

I've tried printing known-missing glyphs like `è`, which every browser (old and new, Mac and Win) shows properly but in a some kind of fallback font.

I've tried printing `&#0;` but it doesn't show what is defined in my actual custom font. IE11 shows the **White Square** `U+25A1`, while every other browser shows the **Replacement Character** `U+FFFD`.

Steps to solve:

1. CSS? Remove all other css `font-family` fallbacks except my custom font. Result: Does not work.
2. CSS? Specify `unicode-range: U+0000;`, does not change anything.
3. Browser? Can confirm browser behavior is the reason I can't see my fallback glyph. Browser shows `serif` as default for undefined glyphs.
4. Question remains: How can I show my font's specific `U+0000 / notdef` in the browser? Maybe it can't be done? May have to create an extra font and fill it with `notdef` glyphs?
5. And why do browsers show `&#0;` as `serif` instead of the custom font's definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to force-show a font's built-in `.notdef` glyph is to go to [unicode-table.com](https://unicode-table.com/en/0000/), click `COPY` and paste the character into my UTF-8 html.

`(&#0;|&#x0;|&#0000;)` each print the font's built-in *Replacement Character* used to replace an unknown, unrecognized, or unrepresentable character. This even applies to fonts as basic as Arial, Times New Roman and Courier + Courier New.

EDIT: Firefox 52-94 will always show it's own built-in `.notdef` character.